# What is the purpose of the AppManifest.xaml file in Silverlight applications?

Tags: silverlight

In opening up the `.xap` file that is generated as output from a Silverlight application I've been tinkering with lately, I noticed a file called `AppManifest.xaml`.

I've also noticed an option in the property pages for the Silverlight project that appears to allow you to optionally not output `AppManifest.xaml` for the project. When unchecking that option, however, I get errors when running the application: `Invalid or malformed application: Check manifest`.

What is the purpose of the `AppManifest.xaml` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this blog post will help: http://blogs.msdn.com/katriend/archive/2008/03/16/silverlight-2-structure-of-the-new-xap-file-silverlight-packaged-application.aspx.  It discusses the .xap file and its parts including the AppManifest.

To save people a link click, in short, it defines the application for deployment, its entry point, and references all the assemblies needed to run.